# specific columns copy from one excel to another excel based on column header name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the columns from one excel to another excel based on the column header name. i have two excel file called "Source" and "Destination" as shown below in the image:

[Source.xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zcPs.png)

[Destination.xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DemZ.png)

i wanted to copy all the columns from source file and paste into to in the destination excel file based on the header file i.e to the yellow shaded columns .Because there are some formula defined in the destination file as shown and it calculates the values from the source file column.

I have tried the basic copy and paste columns. Though it works , it requires lot of manual interventions.

sample piece of code:

```
src.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("A1")

src.Range("B:B").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("E1")

src.Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("I1")
```

i would expect something like to lookup the column header name from source file and destination file and if the names are matched , then it will paste the whole columns in the destination file. As i am very new to excel , can anyone help to solve this through VBA scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SpecificColCopy()
    Dim Wbs As Workbook
    Dim Wbd As Workbook
    Dim Wbm As Workbook
    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim SourceCol As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet, targetWS As Worksheet
    Dim MacroWS As Worksheet
    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Long: SourceHeaderRow = 1
    Dim SourceCell As Range
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wbm = ThisWorkbook
    Set MacroWS = Wbm.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set Wbs = Workbooks.Open("C:\mydirb\Source.xlsx") 'workbook needs to be closed state
    Set sourceWS = Wbs.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set Wbd = Workbooks.Open("C:\mydirb\Destination.xlsx") ''workbook needs to be closed state
    Set targetWS = Wbd.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set TargetHeader = targetWS.Range("A1:N1")
    On Error GoTo 0

    sourceWS.Activate
    For Each Cell In TargetHeader
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set SourceCell = Rows(SourceHeaderRow).Find _
                (Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                SourceCol = SourceCell.Column
                RealLastRow = Columns(SourceCol).Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                If RealLastRow > SourceHeaderRow Then
                    Range(Cells(SourceHeaderRow + 1, SourceCol), Cells(RealLastRow, _
                        SourceCol)).Copy
                    targetWS.Cells(2, Cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next


  MacroWS.Activate
  Wbs.Save
  Wbd.Save
  Wbs.Close
  Wbd.Close
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

 [![Souce_destination][1]][1]
```

Comment: @suresh Glad that it worked for you.Please accept my answer.To mark an answer as accepted, please click on the check mark beside the answer below lower pointing triangle to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.